# Magento 2 installation failed

Tags: magento2, error

I have tried to install Magento2 in my localhost and not able to success every time can you guys tell me if any proper tutorial available for installing Magento in Localhost ?

Comment: Which error you are getting ?

Comment: Please check below URLs for very good tutorial about installing Magento - http://inchoo.net/magento-2/how-to-install-magento-2/ - http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/bk-install-guide.html

Comment: I have tried tutorial provided by @AasimGoriya and its working for me.